# CSS image dynamic resizing

Tags: html, css

I want my background image to dynamically resize when window is resized. It doesn't matter if proportions of image are changed. So the way I try to do this is to set

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

for *img* in *body*.

It does what I want, but image is a tag, so other tags are placed below it on layout, and  I can't find a way to make image ignored by all other tags.

Also I can't find a way to do it for

```
body {
    background-image: url("bckg.jpg");
    //hoooooow?
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your background image to scale according to the window size, why not use the following:

```
body {
    background-image: url("bckg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

So the important line is this: `background-size: cover;` this ensures that the background image "covers" the visible portion of the page

Comment: Thanks so much! Actually it doens't work in appropriate way without
`background-attachment: fixed;`
line. Can you explain please?

Comment: You're welcome! According to W3Schools, the "fixed" value tells the browser that the behaviour of the background-attachment must be fixed to the viewport (the visible portion of the browser page), if you changed it to "scroll", then it would scroll with the page. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want image to crop but to always take 100% of height and width try following:

```
body {
    background: url('example.png') no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h52z358a/2/)

Comment: I found this one more useful

Comment: @dehood  I agree fully.  Besides it applies to divs equally. And simplicty/conciseness takes the cake!